# Creating a program in java that counts sentences, paragraphs, letters and words

Tags: java

I need to create a program that counts the frequency of characters in a text file, as well as the number of paragraphs words and sentences.

I have a problem where when my program outputs the frequency of the letters the program outputs multiple outputs for each letter in the alphabet.

Output should be like this:

if input was "hello world!"

(should output this for all letters of the alphabet):

> The letter a has been found 0 times
>
> the letter b has been found 0 times

(until it reaches the letters that appear and then shows how many times they appear)

> number of paragraphs: 1
>
> number of sentences: 1
>
> number of characters:10
>
> number of words: 2

I have been working on this for weeks now and still can't find a solution.

```
package SuperCounter2;

import java.io.*;

public class SuperCounter2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("//Users//4617621//Desktop//This is the most stupid assignment");
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

    String line;

    int countWord = 0;
    int sentenceCount = 0;
    int characterCount = 0;
    int paragraphCount = 1;
    int whitespaceCount = 0;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        int ci, i, j, k, l = 0;
        char c, ch;
        i = line.length();

        if (line.equals("")) {
            paragraphCount++;
        }

        if (!(line.equals(""))) {
            characterCount += line.length();

            String[] wordList = line.split("\\s+");

            countWord += wordList.length;
            whitespaceCount += countWord - 1;

            String[] sentenceList = line.split("[!?.:]+");
            sentenceCount += sentenceList.length;
        }

         int counter = 0;

        for (int m = 0; m < line.length(); m++) {
            counter++;
        }

        for (c = 'A'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            k = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                 ch = line.charAt(j);
            if(ch == c) {
                k++;
                  System.out.println(" the character " + c + " has occured " + k + " times");
            }
        }
    }
  }

   System.out.println("Total word count = " + countWord);
    System.out.println("Total number of sentences = " + sentenceCount);
    System.out.println("Total number of characters = " + characterCount);
    System.out.println("Number of paragraphs = " + paragraphCount);
    System.out.println("Total number of whitespaces = " + whitespaceCount);

  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity for you to spend some time learning [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code.

Comment: What's the actual output you get?

Comment: You're not saving any information per-letter anywhere.

Comment: he character s has occured 1 times
 the character s has occured 2 times
 the character s has occured 3 times
 the character s has occured 4 times  It will output more than once for each letter of the alphabet.

Comment: Are you sure you need to count upper and lowercase letters separately? If you’re going to keep count of each letter of the alphabet don’t you think it would be more efficient to use more than 1 counter, maybe an array of counters?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could see this as simply counting the number of periods, spaces, carriage returns, etc.

It might be easier to do this by taking it a letter at a time instead of a word at a time.

The only place it would get tricky (where you need to look at more than one thing at a time) is cases where there might be "word1.word2", "word1. word2" or "word1.  word2" (two spaces).  For those you might have to keep a flag that said if the previous character was a "word separator"(Period, space, c/r) then don't count another word.

Otherwise it seems pretty straight forward.  Look at the character, if it is a period add it to the line count&word count, if it's a space add it to the word count, if it's a c/r add it to the paragraph, and word counts, and then track each letter (probably in a Map)

The inside of the loop should be about 5 lines of code if you count the flag manipulation.

Not writing code because this sounds like homework.

PS:  It actually seems like a pretty cool assignment :)

Comment: Your logic is assuming well formated text. (which it might be for education purpose) - But in the real world, counting spaces to count words would most likely `     ` fail       for `    ` sure. As well as dots for sentences.......

Comment: I pointed that out in the third paragraph along with a solution.  If you wanted to add all non-alpha letters to the list of "word separators" described there, that might not be a bad idea.